# Solr Updates which is faster solrj or curl

Tags: solr, solrj

I  have a case where I have a set of fields to be updated in solr. The input  i recieve is in form of a map, key being field name and value is the updated value. 
I had a doubt that in such a scenario should i be using curl to  update the doc or solrj where I have to convert the map to solrInputDocument and then call add command. Will the first approach be faster than second?

Comment: There's an easy way to find out: *Try it*. It will depend on several factors (cloud vs single, caches, batch sizes, IO, etc.), and neither will be an exact answer. Most of time will probably be spent in Solr itself.

Comment: regading map--> solrInputDocument please also see https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/SolrInputDocument.html which uses map you can try in that way also... Seems like it uses LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can convert the map to SolrInputdocument.
- Curl uses HTTP URL. All requests go to HttpSolrServer(Im not quite sure about it).
  However, in my experience, I would strongly recommend
  [***ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer***](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer.html) which is meant for updates

SolrJ has ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer class which describes like below.

> ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer buffers all added documents and writes them
>   into open HTTP connections. This class is thread safe. Params from
>   UpdateRequest are converted to http request parameters. When params
>   change between UpdateRequests a new HTTP request is started. Although
>   any SolrServer request can be made with this implementation, it is
>   only recommended to use ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer with /update
>   requests. The class HttpSolrServer is better suited for the query
>   interface.

The below is example way to get Solr Server instance

```
/**
     * Method lookUpConcurrentUpdateSolrServerInstance.
     * 
     * @param baseURL String
     * @param collection String
     * @return ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer
     * @throws SolrServerException
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient lookUpConcurrentUpdateSolrServerInstance(String baseURL, String collection)
                    throws SolrServerException, IOException, Exception {

        ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient solrServer = null;
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(baseURL) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(collection)) {

            solrServer = new ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient(baseURL + collection, "queueSizeasInteger", 10), 
                            "threadCount as integer", 10));
            checkServerStatus(solrServer);
            return solrServer;
        }

        return solrServer;
    }
```

Comment: Avoid using curl over SOLRJ gives you a more reliability on logging and you can have more stack-trace to re-index the data.

Comment: @RamPrasad G  Is there a utility to convert map to solrinputdocument or we  have to iterate over the map and set values. I have a map of <String,String>

Comment: see convert method http://massapi.com/source/github/73/51/735130622/trunk/adhoc-mdrill/src/main/java/com/alimama/mdrill/index/utils/DocumentConverter.java.html#49